# Fresco Listeners, when are they called?

Tags: android, fresco

Following Fresco's documentations: http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-to-events.html

I've set up a listener to notify me on the events, but what I need to know (and could not find this information anywhere) is if the low-res calls will notify the listeners as well. And if so, how to avoid it, or set a different listener entirely for the low-res calls. For those wondering, Fresco can load a low-res version of an image before loading the high-res version, and this is how the callbacks are called on this is what is confusing me.

This is my code, for reference:

```
/*
   Here we create the controller, aggregating everything that has been done before and some other settings, and set the controller to our view.
*/

PipelineDraweeControllerBuilder builder = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder();
builder.setLowResImageRequest(lowResRequest)
.setImageRequest(request)
.setTapToRetryEnabled(true)
.setControllerListener(controllerListener) // this is the callback listener
.setOldController(container.getController());
DraweeController controller = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to notify about the events of low res request, you need to add a RequestListener to low res request:

```
ImageRequestBuilder.fromRequest(request)
            .setRequestListener(requestListener)
            .build();
```

If the original image request loads faster than low res, Fresco will call the onRequestCancelation on low res image request listener.

Comment: I only want the events of the high-res request. And I do have a custom request for the high-res image as well. Should I set the listener there instead of setting it in the Controller? I'm a little confused to the differences between the controller listener and the request listener.

Comment: Yes, you should set a listener on request, but request listeners are added globally registered in the ImagePipelineConfig and logs all requests. Check the differences on your link: http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-to-events.html 
I think you need the controller listener